# Sample app for kubernetes 1.2.0

Tags: kubernetes

Is there an example app that can be deployed on a kubernetes cluster running v1.2.0? The kubernetes official docs provides an example guestbook which creates deployments, but deployments are not supported on kubernetes v1.2.0.

I was trying to find some sample multi-container pods examples online that have containers running frontend but couldn't find good examples.

Comment: Seen http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/multi-container/#sample-file ?

Comment: the django frontend pod keeps restarting

Comment: Can you provide the log of the django pod?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes 1.2 deployments were released beta. Did your try changing the apiversion to beta.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
```